# @Aspect class with an advice signature similar to pointcut expression

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I was learning AOP and came across a scenario .

**All** of the **classes are within package `com.spring`**
and `Pointcut` defines `@AfterReturning` type of `Advice` ***for any method in any class of package `com.spring` with any number of arguments***.

> `spring.xml` is well defined, in my classpath and the provided code is running

So my question is, shouldn't this advice of `Aspects` class run infinitely as it itself satisfies `Pointcut` definition?

Here's my **Aspect Class**

```
package com.spring;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class Aspects {

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.spring.*.*(..))", returning= "res")
    public void logAfterExecutionAdvice(int res){
        System.out.print("Result in advice: "+res);
         System.out.print(" In After Advice ");
  }
}
```

My **Adder Class**

```
package com.spring;

public class Adder {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    public int add(int a,int b){
       return (a+b);
    }
    /**
     * @return the a
     */
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    /**
     * @param a the a to set
     */
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    /**
     * @return the b
     */
    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }
    /**
     * @param b the b to set
     */
    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

And my **Main Class**

```
package com.spring;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    Adder adder=(Adder)ctx.getBean("adder");
    System.out.print("Result=" + adder.add(2,3));
    }

}
```

The OUTPUT which I get is **Result in advice: 5 In After Advice Result=5**

Comment: no, because your aspect method executes, but doesn't actually return anything.

Comment: It is because advice only executes when the method is called on spring beans and in your case `Adder` bean is maintained by spring and so it advice works only for methods of that bean.

Comment: Is it something that all methods in @Aspect annotated class are excluded from being matched by pointcut expression?

Comment: @ShabbirEssaji Exactly!!

Comment: If you absolutely want to intercept aspects from within other aspects, you need to configure your application to use AspectJ instead of Spring AOP. Then it is no problem.

Comment: Thanks @kriegaex ..Will try that definitely!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Spring's AOP documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) -

> In Spring AOP, it is not possible to have aspects themselves be the
>   target of advice from other aspects. The @Aspect annotation on a class
>   marks it as an aspect, and hence excludes it from auto-proxying.

The classes marks as `@Aspect` are excluded from the auto-proxing and pointcuts.

So, if you try something like this -

```
package com.spring;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class Aspects {
    @After("execution(* com.spring.Aspects.*(..))")
    public void logAfterExecutionAdvice(){
        System.out.print("In After Advice ");
    }
}
```

The Spring will give an error something like -

```
Error:(12, 0) ajc: advice defined in com.spring.Aspects has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
```

Comment: Ohk..Nice!! I didnt read the doc in first place but assumed something like this could be the answer. Thanks!